# Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop on VirtualBox - not showing desktop or anything just black screen after odoo installation

Tags: 18.04, virtualbox

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop edition on VirtualBox, working fine after guest edition installations from virtualbox too. I installed **Odoo 14** using a guide, after successul it showing screen in browser to create first database. at that time I shutdown machine and then start it again but after booting (showing Ubuntu and some dots blow) it is not showing anything on screen, leave it for 10 minutes then used mouse to click, pressing enter key or any other key nothing happened. I have checked on 3 laptop machines and the same behaviour on all ( 1 is Lenovo and other 2 are different versions of HP ). Please help, no screenshot no log files etc. to submit here.
regards

Answer (score 0):

I know getting logs might be difficult but could you share a picture of the screen? while booting pressing F2 would show a detailed log of the boot process you might take a picture when the system halts on a process and share with us. No one would be able to help unless some sort of additional details are provided especially when you're facing issue after installing any third party software. May be someone who worked with Odoo and faced similar issue would instantly identify but any other person here would need a bit more information to proceed. I hope you get it.

Comment: thank @Jijo Joseph for reply, i know it is impossible to get a clue when nothing appears on screen and we can't have any kind of access to system, but just a blank and black screen. will try as instructed (F2) to have something which can help, want to create this VM for Odoo Developers ( I had a Win 10 but always prefer Ubuntu for peace of mind ). ok, thanks again, if have anything, will post here.